# Weird box-shadow in chrome and opera

Tags: css, google-chrome

I want to create a transparent circle.

I have used box-shadow to fill color outside the circle.

Its working fine on mozilla, IE10 and Safari (Works will prefix).

[image]

However, its not working properly in chrome(Version 40.0.2214.111 m) and opera(Version: 27.0.1689.69).

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qExgaB)

**CSS**

```
#overlay {
    height: 442px;
    width: 442px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 204px 0 0 -221px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1000px 1000px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: if you change `box-shadow: 0 0 1000px 1000px` into `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px` the result is the same also on chrome

Comment: can you post an image of what it *should* look like?

Comment: Thanks @FabrizioCalderan I just got it by playing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up with the box-shadow by giving it high values.

I just changed box-shadow form

```
box-shadow: 0 0 1000px 1000px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
```

to

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
```

[Updated code](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/wByNep)